# write non utf8 characters to file in perl

Tags: perl, file, utf-8

Inside a script in perl I am writing strings into a temp file created in the following way:

```
IO::File->new_tmpfile
```

How can I write in the same way, non utf8 characters?

Comment: Well, just use normal operations with an appropriate scalar... Have you tried it at the very least? Oh, and see `pack()`

Comment: "Non utf8" tells us what you *don't* want.  What *do* you want?

Comment: Upvoted: Top answer here actually helped.  TLDR: You have a UTF8 character, not a non-UTF8 character.  As indicated in your debug, "I get an error 'Wide character'", a wide character is a multi-byte character is UTF-8.  Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Your [IO::File](https://metacpan.org/module/IO%3a%3aFile) object has a `binmode` method that works exactly the same way as the [built-in of the same name](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/binmode.html). You use that to set the required I/O layer. You probably want something like:

```
$fh->binmode(':utf8'); # or whatever character encoding you're using
```

Answer (score 0):

`IO::File->new_tmpfile` returns a filehandle. You can just `print` to the filehandle in the usual way.

```
 $fh = IO::File->new_tmpfile;
 print $fh "some stuff to write to the temp file.\n";
```

Comment: In case the char is not a utf8 char, I get an error "Wide character" when printing the usual way.